# Signal Processing

Tags: microcontroller, arduino

Is there any particular hardware/software required and what is called for all the signal processing activities which occur in the Low Voltage Safety Circuit?(eg.PLC,Arduino etc)

Comment: what signal processing activites are you talking about?

Comment: What do you mean by "Low Voltage Safety Circuit"? Please [edit] your question. If you are considering using an Arduino for a critical safety circuit such as in an industrial machine then forget it.

Comment: for an EV Go kart , using a 12V auxiliary circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean if any particular hardware/software is required to process Low Voltage Safety Circuit signals?

- In therms of signal processing, no hardware is needed because you can emulate signals through code (like sin or cos) and process it (programs like Matlab, Octave, etc)
- If you want to process real signals, ADC and maybe DAC hardware modules are needed
- Regarding Low Voltage Safety Circuit I don't understand, what do you mean?

Comment: a typical EV go kart consists of 2 circuits. One is a Normal High Voltage circuit which consists of the controller,motor and battery. Whereas there is also a Low Voltage Safety circuit which acts a backup circuit in case the primary one fails.